# Android Add imagine icon as a "hint" in a textview?

Tags: android

is it possible to add a image icon inside a textviews Hint?

at the moment i can only add text in the hint properties but what i want to do is add a small image icon and a text.

is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to write your own View which could perhaps be based on a FrameLayout which contains both a TextView (with an empty hint) and an ImageView. Alternatively you could simply use a TextView and when it's empty you set a background image to your "hint icon", and clear the background when text has been entered.

Comment: The background option is great when used with a textwatcher to check the length of the text entered.

Comment: sounds quality.so i can in theory set a background for a textview And also have a hint set as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could user setError to display some text and and an image in the textfield but that would be after the user inputs something and you check it.

Alternatives:

1. Use setBackground with your hint icon on the background image
2. Subclass TextView and override the drawing to draw your hint icon

Answer (score 0):

```
    String hint = "<center><img src=\"" + R.drawable.search_hint + "\"/>搜索感兴趣的内容, hello world , I'm form China.</center>";

    Html.fromHtml(hint, new ImageGetter()
    {

        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source)
        {
            int img = Integer.parseInt(source);
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(img);
            drawable.setBounds(0,0,drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

            return drawable;
        }
    }, null);
    searchTxt.setHint(hint);
```